# Design choice for Android app

Tags: android

I am new to Android (but proficient in programming) and I have been reading the Google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide).

I am trying to build a small app, just to get familiar with Android (not a very fancy app, just for learning app dev).
The app would have an initial activity containing a list of items, and the user can view them (through another activity), edit them (again another activity) or create new ones (again another activity). My concern is how to store this list of items in the phone.
I do not intend (at the moment) for the app to be synced with any external service, so I am happy to store all the data in a file. Typically I would be looking at 200 items of small size, so a text file (maybe XML or JSON) would be enough I think (SQL would probably be overkill here).

My question is: if I have an XML file with all the items, do I need to parse it and load it in memory for every activity?
For example:

1. the user enters the app to see the list of items -> must load the XML
2. the user wants to add a new item-> I need to load the XML again to be able to add an XML child

Is this the most natural way of doing this in Android? having to load the same resource over and over in each activity?

Thanks

Comment: If you just have strings to store, use ´SharedPreferences´. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences For more information read the data-storage documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Comment: Don't keep it in memory. But you need to load it every time you use it.

Comment: Use Gson and store List of objects to Json. I can paste some code to show how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse files you may use adapter. You can either create custom adapter  or use default one. Besides that you may know programming concepts such as Design Patterns. My point is to reuse in android can be done programmatically.

In your for storing data would be better to use SharedPreferences  here tutorial to [understand](https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial) idea about it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use SQL to store your data, you can try [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

And yes, you have to load all values in everytime you read or write. But don't worry, it won't be hard for mobile phone hardware.